# Unresolved class : Unable to find explicit activity class from JAR file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am adding a module to my project for which i have to add the activity tag in my AndroidManifest file like below:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActiviy"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

But i am getting an error `Unresolved class 'PaytmPGAcitvity` at android:name line.

I have tried to add the dependency by:

- Importing JAR as module and add module dependency in Project Structure
- Adding dependency by adding external JAR under project structure
- Invalidate cache/restart after above two methods
- Clean project

The project get build and the APK is installed but it give the following error where this PaytmPGActivity is used.

```
com.abc.activities/.xyzActivity, isShadow:false t1246}
02-28 12:39:10.070 25995-25995/com.washkart.activities
W/System.err:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.abc.activities/com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity}; 
have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It is trying to search for activity in my base package i.e. in manifest tag package="com.abc.activities",And the PaytmPGActivity.class in located in the JAR file. How do resolve this issue so that it takes the activity from JAR module instead of the app module.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this piece of code in your manifest -

```
<activity
 android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActiviy"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Change it to -

```
<activity
 android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Its a spelling mistake in Paytm documentation. **PaytmPGActiviy** should be changed to **PaytmPGActivity**

Comment: I am not using the intent to start the activity directly. I am using a Class from the JAR file which **internally** uses this activity.

Comment: Checkout [this link](http://paywithpaytm.com/developer/paytm_sdk_doc?target=android-configurations) which shows how it is being used.

Comment: Changed my answer above. 1. Make sure you are adding the JAR correctly, looks like that is a problem.  Or if you still think everything is correct, you can contact PayTM support to see if anything is missing. Try and reply.

Comment: i have followed both the steps that you have mentioned correctly and re verified it again.

Comment: Still issue is there ? I don't have a computer now to try. I can try making a sample project after 8-10 hrs. I can reply back then if your problem is still there.

Comment: Sure. I'll try to resolve it by researching more till then. If not resolved it would be very helpful if you can try later on your end as well. I'll post an answer if resolved by me.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have been struggling to solve this for last 4 days.